# How to find the tilt of the satellite imagery using Python & Google Maps Static API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-engine

I would like to calculate (or get the metadata of) the tilt of the satellite to the image.

This will help me calculate better angles and distances between objects in the images.

Is there a way to get this data?

---

Following (https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/35764/gbg)[GBG]'s suggestion, I used EXIFTOOL to get the metadata, but it does not seem to have the information I am looking for.

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 12.44
File Name                       : im_name.png
Directory                       : /path/to/dir
File Size                       : 126 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2022:09:02 15:32:38+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2022:09:07 12:08:36+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2022:09:07 12:08:34+02:00
File Permissions                : -rw-r--r--
File Type                       : PNG
File Type Extension             : png
MIME Type                       : image/png
Image Width                     : 400
Image Height                    : 400
Bit Depth                       : 8
Color Type                      : Palette
Compression                     : Deflate/Inflate
Filter                          : Adaptive
Interlace                       : Noninterlaced
Palette                         : (Binary data 762 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Image Size                      : 400x400
Megapixels                      : 0.160
```

Comment: Maybe that information is stored in the EXIF data.  Try using something like EXIFTools or gdalinfo to read the EXIF tags and post the results to your question.   https://exiftool.org/   or  https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html

Comment: You had a tag for Python but have not provided any code attempt so I have removed it.